# Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have research through the internet with this popular error and I have found no solution to my problem.

What I have is a jQuery iframe post message function that receive strings from a different domain. When it get the string it will need to store it to Angular and save to the database. What I am having the trouble is, trying to update angular so that recognizes the changes.

So here is my code:

```
.controller('jobOrderController', function(Jobs, socketio) {
    var vm = this;
    var myImage;
    $.receiveMessage(
            function(e) {
                myImage = e.data;
                vm.$apply(function() {
                    vm.orderData.guideImage = e.data
                });
            },
            'http://aaa.com'
        );

    vm.createOrders = function() {
        vm.message = '';
        Jobs.createOrders(vm.orderData)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.orderData = '';
                vm.message = data.message;
            });
    };

})
```

`$.receiveMessage` will listen for incoming string data and then when it receive it should just save it to my "controller, vm". I know that my message is being received as I can alert them. 
I know that I am going it wrong but everything I read is using `$scope.apply` so I thought it would work the same way using "this". But it doesn't seem to be updated to angular.

Comment: Change `.controller('jobOrderController', function(Jobs, socketio) {` ==> `.controller('jobOrderController', function(vm, Jobs, socketio) {`

Comment: it gave me injection error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
.controller('jobOrderController', function($scope, Jobs, socketio) {
   var vm = this;

   $.receiveMessage(
        function(e) {
            myImage = e.data;
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                vm.orderData.guideImage = e.data
            });
        },
        'http://aaa.com'
    );

});
```

The `this` works differently inside the Angular's controller. It's not always same as the `$scope` and `$scope` is the object which contains `$apply` method.

Comment: Yeah but this will kill my controller as ctrler leaving it un-responsive.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer. Just use `$scope` instead of `vm` when calling `$apply`.

Comment: thank alot... it tuck me awhile to apply your code as i had to change different things throughout different script. But yes it works

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using [john papa's guideline](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers) to avoid the use of `$scope`.
You just forgot to declare vm (standing for viewmodel) at the beginning of your controller:

```
var vm = this;
```

EDIT: the guideline also says :

> "Consider using $scope in a controller only when needed. For example
>   when publishing and subscribing events using $emit, $broadcast, or
>   $on."

For `$apply` as well, you need to explicitly use `$scope.$apply`

Comment: Ops sorry i forgot to add that line in, i made the adjustment to my post now

Comment: Ahh i see, ok i think i will just replace everything to $scope

Comment: Sure, using $scope every times will work absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

For `$apply`, you can not use `this`. `$scope` and `this` are different instance so `this` can not access `$apply`.

Check snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      vm.text = 'Submit';
    });
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  <button>{{ctrl.text}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `controllerAs` syntax is just (currently) sugar for `$scope.foo` (if your `controllerAs` is set to `foo`). As a result, `this` will *actually* point at `$scope.foo` in this instance and not `$scope`, which is why you will be unable to invoke any of `$scope`'s actions through `this`. To use any of those, you will have to explicitly use `$scope`.

The above answers all answer with a solution on how to fix the short-term problem, that is, you using `$scope.$apply` in the controller.

Honestly, the issue here isn't that you can't use `$scope.$apply` - I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but one of the main rules of Angular is that you have to do everything through Angular; `$.receiveMessage` is decidedly *not* Angular. Wrap your `$.receiveMessage` into a service; that service should also handle the `$scope.$apply`. This will help reduce code duplication and make your controller agnostic to the implementation of the service.

There may already be a library that exists that does this that avoids using the heavy requirement of jQuery.